# tf tree in namespace

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf-tree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to see my tf tree (rqt_tf_tree, tf view_frames, etc.) for a namespaced robot. I can't seem to get the system to behave the way I want it to. I have tried setting the `ROS_NAMESPACE` environment variable to my namespace, and then running `rosrun tf view_frames` and `rqt_tf_tree`, but it simply shows that no tf tree exists. I can see the tree exists in RViz, as well as by echoing `/namespace/tf` and `/namespace/tf_static`. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331979/tf-tree-in-namespace/) by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2019-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

NVM, figured it out.

Just needed to remap `/tf` and `/tf_static` per [here](https://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments).

E.g. `rosrun tf view_frames /tf:=/namespace/tf /tf_static:=/namespace/tf_static`

---

Originally posted by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) with karma: 261 on 2019-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0